# Deeply nested params in Rails doesn't change value from form to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a weird bug from Ruby on Rails. I don't know if it's a bug or whatever, but before I report this I just want to make sure.

I have a polymorphic table that belongs_to 2 models.

*polymorphic table*

```
module Spree
  class AccountPrice < Spree::Base
    validates :accountable, presence: true

    belongs_to :accountable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :variant_price_set, class_name: "Spree::VariantPriceSet"
    belongs_to :shipping_method_price_set, class_name: "Spree::ShippingMethodPriceSet"

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :variant_price_set, :shipping_method_price_set
    
  end
end
```

My CorporateAccount can have many of those polymorphic tables.

```
class Spree::CorporateAccount < Spree::Base
  has_many :account_prices, as: :accountable, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_prices
end
```

So on my corporate edit view, I have this.

```
<%= f.fields_for :account_prices do |ff| %> 
      <div class="row">
         <%= ff.fields_for :variant_price_set do |fff|%>
           <div class="col-md-2" >
             <%= fff.text_field :id %>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2">
              <%= fff.text_field :name %>
           </div>
         <% end %>

         <%= ff.fields_for :shipping_method_price_set do |fff|%>
           <div class="col-md-2">
              <%= fff.text_field :id %>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2">
             <%= fff.text_field :name %>
           </div>
         <% end %>

         <div class="col-md-2">
          start_date: <%= ff.text_field :exp_start_date%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
           end_date: <%= ff.text_field :exp_end_date%>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md">
          staus: <%= ff.text_field :status%>
       </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

and on my corporate controller, I have this.

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    class CorporateAccountsController < ResourceController
      def update
        
        if @corporate_account.update_attributes(corporate_account_params)
          flash.now[:success] = Spree.t(:corporate_account_updated)
        end

        render :edit
      end

      def corporate_account_params
        params.require(:corporate_account).permit(:company_id,
                                                  :company_name,
                                                  :shipping_category_id,
                                                  :variant_price_set_id,
                                                  :shipping_method_price_set_id,
                                                  :corporate_token,
                                                  :corporate_token_confirmation,
                                                  :account_key,
                                                  :managed,
                                                  :billing_type,
                                                  :tax_exempt,
                                                  ship_address_attributes: permitted_address_attributes,
                                                  bill_address_attributes: permitted_address_attributes,
                                                  account_prices_attributes: [
                                                    :id, :exp_start_date, :exp_end_date, :status,
                                                    shipping_method_price_set_attributes: [:id, :name], 
                                                    variant_price_set_attributes: [:id, :name]
                                                  ]
                                                 )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

everything on that strong params update. except for the deeply nested ones. The `shipping_method_price_set_attributes` and `variant_price_set_attributes`.

So when I change the Id on any of the price sets and catch it on corporate controller using VS Code breakpoint the params value doesn't change. Like when I input 3 and hit the break point check the params its still the previous data. I think this is a bug, because before that I has `variant_price_set` it was updating fine, but when I added `shipping_method_price_set` it doesn't update any more.

**Sample params**

```
{
  "utf8": "✓",
  "authenticity_token": "IOZB+SbHtP+rrK2j1LqI039lOe8BB95vQXChUERb8dWNcM+YqUSaur3wMxWHmxDWFyIq8SkvQ9E7aJmv7TV5iw==",
  "corporate_account": {
    "company_id": "waaaaaaaaaa",
    "company_name": "QQQ",
    "corporate_token": "",
    "corporate_token_confirmation": "",
    "account_key": "",
    "tax_exempt": "0",
    "billing_type": "creditcard",
    "shipping_category_id": "",
    "account_prices_attributes": {
      "0": {
        "variant_price_set_attributes": {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Another Test Price Set"
        },
        "shipping_method_price_set_attributes": {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Test Shipping Method Price Set 2"
        },
        "exp_start_date": "2019-10-11 17:42:36 UTC",
        "exp_end_date": "2019-11-10 17:42:36 UTC",
        "status": "temporary",
        "id": "2"
      },
      "1": {
        "variant_price_set_attributes": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Test Price Set"
        },
        "shipping_method_price_set_attributes": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Test Shipping Method Price Set"
        },
        "exp_start_date": "2019-10-11 17:42:36 UTC",
        "exp_end_date": "2019-10-11 17:42:36 UTC",
        "status": "temporary",
        "id": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  "button": "",
  "id": "1"
}
```

### Update 1

Network tab post request:

```
corporate_account[company_id]: waaaaaaaaaa
corporate_account[company_name]: QQQ
corporate_account[corporate_token]: 
corporate_account[corporate_token_confirmation]: 
corporate_account[account_key]: 
corporate_account[tax_exempt]: 0
corporate_account[billing_type]: creditcard
corporate_account[shipping_category_id]: 
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][variant_price_set_attributes][id]: 3
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][variant_price_set_attributes][id]: 2
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][shipping_method_price_set_attributes][id]: 2
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][shipping_method_price_set_attributes][id]: 2
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][exp_start_date]: 
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][exp_end_date]: 
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][status]: default
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][id]: 2
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][1][variant_price_set_attributes][id]: 3
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][1][variant_price_set_attributes][id]: 1
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][1][shipping_method_price_set_attributes][id]: 2
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][1][shipping_method_price_set_attributes][id]: 1
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][1][exp_start_date]: 
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][1][exp_end_date]: 
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][1][status]: default
corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][1][id]: 1
```

### Update 2

So I made a request using Insomnia with the same params structure. but when I try to change these values

```
"variant_price_set_attributes": {
          "id": "1"
        },
        "shipping_method_price_set_attributes": {
          "id": "1"
        },
```

I got a routing error. this is weird.

### Update 2.1

So I found another weird thing. for some reason on Insomnia when trying to debug this out. When I change the value of `variant_price` or `shipping_method` I will get this stack error

```
Started PUT "/spree/admin/corporate_accounts" for ::1 at 2019-10-14 12:06:55 -0700
User excluded error: #<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [PUT] "/spree/admin/corporate_accounts">

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/spree/admin/corporate_accounts"):
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
```

If you check the User excluded error it says no route matches its because the ID number of corporate_accounts is lost for some unknown reason. The route should be `/spree/admin/corporate_accounts/1`.

Comment: can you post an example of the params as they get sent?

Comment: @RockwellRice there you go. I can update everything. just price set is blocking me. this is like a bug or something.

Comment: You're permitting `account_prices_attributes` as an `array`, but it's a `hash`, no?

Comment: @jvillian wait im confused. does it matter? im just permitting them as the attributes. I dont think it matter if a hash or an array because the association will now about it right?

Comment: TBH, I'm not 100%. I don't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` because I often find it harder than just doing it bare knuckles. What does it say in your console? Is there an unpermitted parameters message?

Comment: before its unpermitted parameters but I added `shipping_method_price_set_attributes` and `variant_price_set_attributes`. after that I got no errors. whe I tried to update nothing. no error no issues with params. God damn this. I had this problem at 11am and its clock out time. lols @jvillian

Comment: If you do a `puts` of `corporate_account_params`, what do you see? I feel your pain. At least you're coding. I'm just over here writing business plans.

Comment: try calling `if @corporate_account.update!(corporate_account_params)` and see what it yells at you about

Comment: @jvillian the same thing as params. Whats really weird its not changing value from views to controller. what I mean is when I check params at least it should change the value right? but it doenst.

Comment: @MarkMerritt samething bro. doesnt update because params doesnt change values.

Comment: @jvillian I posted another info. I checked the network tab and got 2 of these 
`corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][variant_price_set_attributes][id]`

`corporate_account[account_prices_attributes][0][shipping_method_price_set_attributes][id]`

one changes the value but the other doesn't maybe this is the culprit. but how though? I cant see other attributes being called by the view.